# MongoDB collection size on windows, how insert large data?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, nosql

I am using MongoDB last version(64 bit), I want to insert large data into collections, for example 3 millions. I am using java mongo driver.
Collections one item is

```
  "_id": ObjectId("54ef7b31fa435e54747f3975"),
   "splitRatio": "1.0",
   "adjClose": "8.4199657167121",
   "ex_Dividend": "0.0",
   "date": "1985-09-27",
   "close": "8.81",
   "adjVolume": "3000.0",
   "id": NumberLong(13379),
   "open": "8.81",
   "simbol": "AAME",
   "adjOpen": "8.4199657167121",
   "adjHigh": "8.4199657167121",
   "volume": "1200.0",
   "high": "8.81",
   "reportDate": ISODate("1985-09-26T19: 00: 00.0Z"),
   "low": "8.81",
   "adjLow": "8.4199657167121"
```

Memory and CPU is a lot, not important i do bulk insert or insert one object from another, every time it stops when items size 13381 .
I made collection by hand and set size to 10 GB .

I do not know with which configuration run mongodb for save large data. I have one node.
For example for mysql 3 mln row in the table no problem.

Whats wrong?
[image: screen]

also mongodb created two files for database, each size is 2,146,435,072 , may be some limit?
![stats][2]
[image: new stats]

[2]:

Comment: ...so what's the problem?

Comment: I cant insert much data, only 13381 and operation stop

Comment: Can you provide the output of `db.<collection>.stats()`?

Comment: Hi, I added screen with stats result.

Comment: What happen when you add a single entry to your colletion? [After 13381 insertion]

Comment: Nothing, manually just added new collection, manually works. But from application I read CSV file and make collection and do bulk insert, mongo conn . pool size I set 3 million.

Comment: I created standalone project, which just insert into mongodb, no Spring, no Tomcat, no beans,and its work now:)

Comment: I'm also creating a csv app reading and I had similar problem, but I was creating a lot of connection.
Might you put the code where you're executing the inserts!!?
I guess that you have a loop.
Maybe loop not ends.

Answer (score 0):

I created standalone project, which just insert into mongodb, no Spring, no Tomcat, no beans,and its work now:)